# On mobile L - inspector - I have a white space on the right due to a DIV

Tags: html, css

Check this photos: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCzfA.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDnli.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3C61.png) and the same applied for the footer

this is my html, the DIV I am talking about is the one with class information. If i remove it everything is fine. But i cant understand how to let it fit in the page in a way that the navbar and the footer don't get the white space on the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      </head>
      
      
      <body>
    
    
        <!-- navbar -->
    
    
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    
            <div class="navbar-brand">
              <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo nordic barista cup"></a>
            </div>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <div class="d-lg-flex flex-column align-items-end ml-md-auto form-search pt-1">
                
                <div class="form-group has-search">
                  <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                  <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
      
                <div class="reponsive-links">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link pt-0" href="#">ABOUT NBC</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link pt-0" href="#">2011 EVENT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link pt-0" href="#">NORDIC ROASTER</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link pt-0" href="#">RESULTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link pt-0" href="#">LINKS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link pt-0" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
    
            </div>
          </nav>
    
        <!-- cover  -->
    
        <section class="cover">
          <div class="coffe-images jumbotron m-0 rounded-0">
          </div>
          <div class="social d-flex justify-content-aound p-4">
            <div class="quote">
              <h3><q>To create an environment in which knowledge about coffee and its sphere can be obtained</q></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 social-links d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-meetup"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- articles -->
    
        <section class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between section-articles p-0">
    
          <div class="articles col-lg-8 col-md-12 pt-4">
            <div class="card-article mb-2">
              <img src="img/kbh.jpg">
              <div class="card-article-infos">
                <h4>Wonderful Copenhagen 2011</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem
                  egestas vitae scel<span id="dots1">...</span><span id="more1"  style='display:none'>I hope I get the internsip. Maecenas nisl est,
                    ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa.Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor
                    porta.</span></p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                  <button onclick="myFunction(1)" id="myBtn1">Read more</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card-article mb-2">
              <img src="img/kbh.jpg">
              <div class="card-article-infos">
                <h4>Wonderful Copenhagen 2011</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi
                  lorem
                  egestas vitae scel<span id="dots2">...</span><span id="more2"  style='display:none'>I hope I get the internsip. Maecenas nisl est,
                    ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa.Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar
                    nibh tempor
                    porta.</span></p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                  <button onclick="myFunction(2)" id="myBtn2">Read more</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card-article mb-2">
              <div class="card-image"><img src="img/kbh.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card-article-infos">
                <h4>Wonderful Copenhagen 2011</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi
                  lorem
                  egestas vitae scel<span id="dots3">...</span><span id="more3" style='display:none'>I hope I get the internsip. Maecenas nisl est,
                    ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa.Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar
                    nibh tempor
                    porta.</span></p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                  <button onclick="myFunction(3)" id="myBtn3">Read more</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="information col-md-4 col-s-12 pt-4">
            <div class="single-info">
              <h3>NBC Shop</h3>
              <p>Your shopping cart is empty <br><a href="url">Visit the shop</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="single-info">
              <h3>Next Event</h3>
              <p>NORDIC BARISTA CUP 2011 <br> Copenhagen, Denmark <br> Dates: 3<sup>rd</sup> - 27<sup>th</sup> August 2011 <br> Theme: SENSORY</p>
            </div>
            <div class="single-info">
              <h3>Scoreboard</h3>
              <p>List of winner from the past years</p>
              <p>2011 - ? <br> 2010 - Sweden <br> 2009 - Denmark <br> 2008 - Norway <br> 2007 - Sweden <br> 2006 - Norway <br> 2005 - Denmark </p>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        </section>
    
        <!-- footer -->
    
    
          <footer>
            <div class="container footer">
              <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
    
                <div class="col-md-4 segment-one py-3">
                  <h3>About Nordic Barista Cup</h3>
                  <p>The vision within the Nordic Barista Cup is:</p>
                  <p><q>To create an environment in which knowledge about coffee and its sphere can be obtained</q></p>
                  <p>'..create an environment..'<br>Combined with personally absorption having the opportunity to see and experience
                    countries,
                    people, traditions etc. will always serve as a source of inspiration in our daily work. The organization behind the
                    Nordic Barista Cup see it as its main purpose
                    to be a part of creating this forum in which people can meet, bond and achieve further knowledge </p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-4 segment-two py-3">
                  <h3>NBC Flickr Stream</h3>
                  <div class="container pl-0">
                    <div class="row p-0 m-0">
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row p-0 m-0">
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row p-0  m-0">
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                      <div class="coffee-box m-0  p-1"> <img src="img/coffee.jpg" alt="cofee grid image"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-4 segment-three py-3">
                  <h3>Contact</h3>
                  <p><strong>Nordic Barista Cup</strong></p>
                  <p>Amagertorv 13, 1160 Copenhagen K <br> +45 33 12 04 28 <br> CVR: 11427693 <br> Email: bbrend@nordicbaristacup.com</p>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-meetup"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                </div>
    
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
    
    
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="js/scripts.js" ></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

my CSS for navbar:

```
    .navbar {
      background-color: #111111;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .logo {
      width: 330px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .has-search .form-control {
        padding-left: 2.375rem;
    }
    
    .has-search .form-control-feedback {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      display: block;
      width: 2.375rem;
      height: 2.375rem;
      line-height: 2.375rem;
      text-align: center;
      pointer-events: none;
      color: #aaa;
    }
    .has-search input {
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    
    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 376px)   {
      
      .logo{
        width: 270px;
      }
      .navbar-toggler-icon {
        font-size: 0.8em;
      }
      
      .has-search .form-control{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        height: 2.1rem;
        border-radius: 50px;
        padding-left: 2.375rem;
      }
      .has-search .form-control-feedback {
        padding-left: 0.4em;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 320px) {
      .logo{
        width: 220px;
      }
    }
```

MY CSS for the main:

```
    @import "navbar.css";
    @import "footer.css";
    
    
    /* cover image section */
    
    .jumbotron {
      background-image: url("../img/coffee1.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      height: 80vh;
      background-position: center;
    }
    
    .cover {
      background-color: #111111;
      color: #646668f3;
    }
    
    .cover h3 q {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .social-links a {
      background-color: #303234;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 2.5em;
      height: 2.5em;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0.2em;
    }
    .social-links a i {
      color: #bab8b6;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    }
    
    
    
    
    /* articles section  */
    
    .information {
      background: linear-gradient(rgb(228, 225, 224), white);
    }
    
    .card-article .card-article-infos {
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    #more {display: none;
    }
    
    .card-article {
      overflow: hidden;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    
    .card-article img {
      height: 100%;
      width: 200px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .card-article p {
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    .card-article{
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .card-article >div>div{
      position:absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 20px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 376px) {
    
      .social .quote h3 q {
        font-size: 1.250rem;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .section-articles, .social {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    
      .social-links {
        padding-top: 1rem ;
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 320px) {
      .social .quote h3 q  {
          font-size: 1.15rem
        }
      }
    }
```

MY CSS for the footer:

```
    footer {
      background-color: #111111;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .segment-one p, .segment-three p  {
      color: #646668f3;
    }
    
    
    .segment-one q {
      color: #bab8b6;
    }
    
    .segment-two img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .segment-three strong   {
      color: #bab8b6;
    }
    
    .segment-three a {
      background-color: #303234;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 2.5em;
      height: 2.5em;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .segment-three a i {
      color: #bab8b6;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 992px){
      
      .footer p {
        font-size: 0.5rem;
      }
    
       .footer h3 {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
       }
    
    .segment-two img {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    .segment-three a {
      width: 1.875em;
      height: 1.875em;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .segment-three a i {
      color: #bab8b6;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      padding: 6px 6px;
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: I see no white space, can you post an Image or clarify it more?

Comment: I added the photo on the question

Comment: it seems that information div is not included in the page

Comment: in other words, that even though the div (information) is inside the section tag, in the web page they appear outside and next the section element?

Comment: try overflow-x: hidden; for the body.

Comment: I tried your code, there is no problem with the element with class: information.